# Accessing Wordpress with google custom search

Tags: php, wordpress, google-custom-search

This is probably a ignorant question but is there a url that all wordpress hosted sites use?

say if i used the "site: www.example.com" to refine my google search it would limit the search only to sites hosted by wordpress.

and if this isn't possible can you use google custom search to do a normal google search from within your site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the first case is not possible. but if you need your users to use google to search within your site you use one of the many google search plugins, like WP Google Search. They will over ride your custom search system with the one from google.